# Quarkus dev mode shows no static files

Tags: java, jar, quarkus

I have some java web application with Quarkus. And it works perfect with runner.jar file. But when i use quarkus:dev mode it shows no static content (only a white background). And thats weird, because the REST Services work properly.
And yes I copy all web resources into main/resources/META-INF when I compile the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working with the runner jar and not in dev mode, it's a bug.

Could you open an issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus ?

Please provide a reproducer and give as much information as possible on your environment (Windows/MacOS or Linux, typically, I know we often have issues with Windows).

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, already found a solution.
Quarkus in dev mode always takes the index.html from main/resources/META-INF, but I rewrite it with maven-resources-plugin in compile.
I thought it takes the index.html from target/classes/resources/META-INF